# Why does flask look for my python file in $HOME?

Tags: python, flask

When I run a flask program in debug mode, it tries to reload my program file from `$HOME`, which of course fails.

- Why is is trying to read from `$HOME`?
- How can I stop this behavior, and make it reload from the directory where it resides?

```
/tmp% cat test_flask.py 

import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/foo', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # app.run(debug=False) -- everything works as expected when debug is False.
    app.run(debug=True)

/tmp% python3 test_flask.py 
 * Serving Flask app "test_flask" (lazy loading)
[...]
/opt/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/mark/test_flask.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here are details on my python:

```
/tmp% which python3
/Users/mark/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
/tmp% file $(which python3)
/Users/mark/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Comment: Is `python` a shell alias?  Show us the output of `which python`

Comment: @JohnGordon, done.  It is an executable.

Comment: It's odd that `python3` is `/Users/mark/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3`, and yet the error refers to `/opt/bin/python3`.

Comment: Where is your file `test_flask.py` located? Can you share the path (you can share the output of `pwd`)

Comment: @ybl the output clearly shows it is in `/tmp`.

Comment: Thanks! Any reason you are using `python foo.py` over `flask run`? There may be some internals related to flask as described here which can cause that problem. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/cli/#application-discovery

Comment: @ybl, that's it... debugging requires the flask command.  Make that into an answer if you like and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging a Flask application relies on internal application discovery mechanism detailed [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/cli/#application-discovery). Invoking the application using `flask` or `python3 -m flask` to debug might help here.